# Creating Viewsheds in Graphic Modeler

Tags: qgis, viewshed, qgis-modeler

I am trying to use Graphic Modeler to run viewsheds. As I can’t appear to use the Viewshed Analysis plugin tool in Graphic Modeler and I instead need to use the GRASS command `r.viewshed`.

I am struggling to understand how to use `r.viewshed`, particularly when trying to run simultaneous viewsheds from multiple points.

I hope to create a viewshed over a distance of 5 Km. for a number of random points (Between 50 and 150) all located within a shapefile and to represent a large area (Solar Park).

I have attached a screenshot of the settings I would normally use in the viewshed plugin tools.

[image]

This is how the output would normally look:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: With some python knowledge you could try to adapt the plugin into a script that would run from the processing toolbox, and thus could be run as part of the model builder. http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/processing_python_scripts.html

Comment: I have followed the tutorial like you suggested, however even though I have copied it word for word, I still get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.6/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptEditorDialog.py", line 228, in runAlgorithm
    exec(self.editor.text(), _locals)
  File "<string>", line 21
    QgsProcessingParameterField)
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Would you be able to explain what this error means?

Comment: You can check this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/339423/using-viewshed-graphical-modeler/341208#341208